# Getting null value when trying to get autofull textbox through javascript in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I'm trying to populate a textbox when a dropdown filed is filled with data. But I'm getting null in result.When I'm passing the 'id' it's returning value but when I'm passing a name it's returning null

Controller

```
public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
    {
        $bottle = Productnames::findOne($catid);
        echo Json::encode($bottle);
    }
```

Javascript code in _form

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$('#catid').change(function(){   
    var catid = $(this).val();

     $.get('index.php?r=production/productnames/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        alert(data);

    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

screenshot of the error
[image: Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you pass parameter to findOne() as string by default it's a primary key field. In your case you have to pass as array like `findOne(['catid'=>$catid])`

But if you want your controller to accept either id or name then try this:

```
public function actionGetForProduction()
        {
            if($id=Yii::$app->request->get('id')){
                 $bottle = Productnames::findOne($id);
               }
            elseif($catid=Yii::$app->request->get('catid')){
                 $bottle=Productnames::findOne(['catid'=>$catid]);
               }
            echo Json::encode($bottle);
        }
```